# Recent update network issues(Ubuntu 22.04.02)

Tags: networking, internet, dns

I have a network issue in my laptop with Ubuntu 22.04.02. It is showing on screen that it got connected to internet but when I open Gmail and all, I either get an screen saying DNS not found, when I open YouTube I get no internet on screen but on wifi connection it's connected. Can you please help me out with what to do? Even on ethernet it shows connected but network issues there too....

Comment: If you know your providers DNS server IP address you can set it in the ethernet configuration, or if your internet router provides DNS services you can use that, or you can set it to 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8. but without DNS servers your internet connection will not find any domains.

Comment: Is this a Desktop or Server installation? Can you focus on one connection at a time? Either wired or WiFi? Are you defining static IP addresses or getting them via DHCP? How are you setting up and defining your connections? What is output of `ip a`? What is output of `resolvectl status`? Please update your question with this information.